# Using distance formula to measure "power distance"

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to estimate distance between two wifi measures, using n dimensional distance formula:

$$
d(P_1, P_2) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(AP_{i,2} - AP_{i,1})^2}
$$

where 'n' its the number of access points measured, and 'AP' the wifi power signal in mW. The point of that is get the distance between device wifi scan and some locations where I saved and stored wifi power signal. By selecting the less distance, I can determine (with some accuracy) device location.

My question is:

1. Can I use this formula for power units, or its just for metric space?
2. Is there some formula better for this purposes?

P.S. I have read this previous Question

[Statistics formula for wifi positioning.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446342/statistics-formula-for-wifi-positioning)

and its [Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446342/statistics-formula-for-wifi-positioning/446356#446356), but I can't use this formula because of building features.

Comment: It might be better to refer to this as three-dimensional distance, using $n$ points of measurement.  Note that power decreases with the inverse square of distance, so a location (of a device) would optimize an expression (possibly using a least squares fit) of predicted vs. measured power levels.

Comment: I recommend that you give some details of what "building features" cause difficulty in applying the earlier Question and Answer.  This context would give Readers a better understanding of what your problem is and likely motivate a response specific to your needs.